# Reverse Flatlists in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i used Flatlist in my app.

i want to reverse those Flatlists.

i tried to reverse my data(**{allDataFiltered.reverse()}**) in the flatlist ,

it is working fine for the first time but not always.

```
<SalaryCardFlatList
  inverted={true}
  data={allDataFiltered}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <AllSalaryCard
      month={item.MONTH_HEBREW}
      year={item.SHOTEF}
      amount={"₪ " + item.NETO_TASHLUM}
      cardColor={item.cardColor}
      handleActionFromParent={() => {
        goToSpecificSalaryScreen(item);
      }}
    />
  )}
/>;
```

i am already using inverted for this but the cards started from middle.
[image]
As you can see,the  cards started from middle.

it is going under the bar chart sheet.

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: use  inverted={true} inbuilt method of flatlist

Comment: this issue is coming from inverted..i already mentioned in my code.

Comment: is that hidden card is your first object in your array? or can you say the index of that card?

Comment: those are not hidden.when you are coming to this first time it is showing like above and if you scroll. up then you can see all cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a big picture of your project, I have set up a small project to reverse the Alphabetic letters.

https://snack.expo.dev/@emmbyiringiro/94b46d

Check and let me know if what you want to achieve.

Comment: const temp = [...data].reverse();
this is working for me.

Comment: Arrays and objects are referential data types, Array.sort or array.reverse mutate original array. This mutation doesn't trigger a new rerender in React. It's best practice to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using sort() to allDataFiltered

Comment: no sort() is not working..